# Uncaught Error: Type mismatch in Date value

Tags: javascript

I am using Google chart and need to specify date in JS format.

```
 arrdata.addColumn('date','ObservationDateTime');
```

As it needs JS format date, I converted SQL date to JS date and now it looks like this

```
2014,08,01
```

However, I still get an error that says ::

```
Uncaught Error: Type mismatch. Value 2014,08,01 
does not match type date in column index 0
```

How do I fix this ? Why do I get this error when date looks in JS format to me?\

**Edit:**

Here is how I am converting and forwarding it in json.

```
String dateString = DateTime.toString();
StringTokenizer dateTokens = new StringTokenizer(dateString,"-");
String ObservationDateTime = "";
    while(dateTokens.hasMoreTokens()){
        String tokenIs = dateTokens.nextToken();
        ObservationDateTime = ObservationDateTime  + tokenIs +",";
    }
    int finalDateLength = ObservationDateTime.length();
    ObservationDateTime = ObservationDateTime.substring(0,finalDateLength-1);
String ObservationSource = rs.getString("ObservationSource");

float observationValue = rs.getFloat("ObservationValue");


obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("ObservationDateTime", ObservationDateTime);
Details.add(obj);
}
resobj.put("Details", Details);
out.write(resobj.toString());

}
```

Comment: Try to pass Date object instead of string.

Comment: @dfsq: I added it to JSON object after converting to this format and this date is retrieved from JSON object only.

Comment: AFAIK `2014,08,01` is not a valid date format anywhere.

Comment: I just needed to use new Date(2014,08,01) before adding it to column of data type date.